# Where do you disable Google Timeline on the Android phone?

Tags: google-maps, gps-tracking, oneplus-x

On OnePlus phone to my surprise, all my location was automatically sent to Google Timeline which I don't remember I actually agreed on such thing.

At what point it was enabled and how do I disable such option completely on the phone?

I'm aware that I can Pause Location History online at [Google Timeline](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/timeline), but I'm looking for option on the phone, not to pause online, but to disable it completely for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to Settings, then Location.
- Find Google Location Settings and individually switch off both Location Reporting and Location History.
- Underneath Location History, select “*Delete Location History*” to wipe clean the cache of locations.
- Repeat the steps for every Google account you have registered.

*Note that disabling all location-finding features will throw a monkey wrench into the functioning of some  apps, so it’s wise to carefully consider which you want to strip of location services*